# Programmatically generate cache with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, caching, auto-generate

I have a huge page that I'm caching with rails caches_page command.
Before the cache has been generated the first http request takes about 30 seconds to generate the cache. I would like to avoid this so the first user hitting the page can load it much faster.

I'm trying to generate the cache programmatically with http but this doesn't seem to work:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://mydomain.com/huge_page")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
```

What I got as response is a timeout error:

```
Timeout::Error (execution expired)
```

Do you have any suggestion how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate the cache by way of an HTTP request, you have to make sure you aren't making that request in the context of your original request. Meaning the page would be requesting itself.

If you're doing that and you have only a single thread or server running your app, it will never be able to complete the request and will timeout. This is because the action won't complete until it finishes the `response = http.request(request)` part. However your server won't be able to respond because it's in the middle of an action.

However, all this is to say that you should really **never** under any circumstances have a request that takes that long to load. Anything that takes more than one second (or, in production, like 200ms) should be moved into a Delayed::Job worker or a similar background queue.

Without knowing the details of your app, I would highly recommend coming up with a way to generate the page much, much faster rather than relying on caching here.

Comment: The cached version of this page is very fast (under 200 ms), it's just computationally complex for the requests it does the first time it's executed. I don't think Delayed::Job can help me this time.

Comment: What about the original point about having one thread/process, can you serve several requests at once?

Comment: Yes, I set up 4 workers so it should be possible to serve more than one request at once.

Comment: If you could explain why it's so computationally complex, it would help to clarify what alternatives might be available. I feel like a page like this is not really how Rails is supposed to be used.